# find if two vectors are correlated

Tags: correlation, pearson-r

I have two vectors of data measurements. I've used the Pearson metric to find out if they are correlated but it didn't return a satisfactory result. Before I put an end and say that those two aren't correlated is there another metric that I can use? Thank you for your time.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Could you explain what you mean by an "unsatisfactory result"?  Would it be one that suggests Pearson correlation might not be appropriate for your data or would it merely be one that you don't like?  And if it's the latter, we would need to explore the reasons for your concern and therefore will need to know about why you are computing a correlation and what the consequences of making an incorrect conclusion might be.

Comment: Can you include a scatterplot of your data?

Comment: @whuber thanks for your answer. What i meant is that it return .6 meaning that they are neither correlated nor uncorrelated. So as you say I don't like the result and I though I could use some other metric to find if those vectors are correlated

Comment: Any nonzero Pearson correlation coefficient is an indication of correlation, not lack thereof.  If the ".6" is instead the *p-value* of a test, then the next step (actually the first step) is to view a scatterplot of the data, as @Stephan suggests, to verify that they form a classic football-shaped cloud.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These are very persistent series to my eye. In my opinion, you should get Pearson correlation on differences, i.e. changes from period to period. For instance if you have series: $y_i,v_i$, then get the correlation between $\Delta y_i=y_i-y_{i-1}$ and $\Delta v_i=v_i-v_{i-1}$. It will surely be lower than between the levels.

Another point is that you should look at not only the correlation itself but associated p-value (significance). If you obtain significant correlation, i.e. anything different that zero, then you have correlated series. For instance, if your correlation coefficient is 0.6 and it's significant in a sense that its p-value is less than, say, 0.05 or 0.01, then you got correlated series. Any statistical software should produce both the correlation coefficient and its significance